# How to use click listener in custom dialog fragment?

Tags: android

```
class CustomDialogFragment: DialogFragment(){ 

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
    val dialogview = LayoutInflater.from(requireActivity()).inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null)
    val oktextview = dialogview.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.YES)
        
    oktextview.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("tag","printif it works") //doesn't print
    }
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null))
        builder.create()
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
  }
}
```

I'm using custom dialog, and wanna use `setOnClickListener` for components of custom dialog.

I did it into `onViewCreated`, but doesn't work.

How can I implement `setOnClickListener` for `TextView` in custom dialog please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a different instance of the view for the onViewCreated method. This means the clicks listener is being set on a view that is not shown to the user.

You can achieve what you want doing the following:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return activity?.let {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(it)
        val inflater = requireActivity().layoutInflater
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialog, null))
        val dialog = builder.create()
        val oktextview = dialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.YES)
    
        oktextview.setOnClickListener {
            Log.i("tag","printif it works") //doesn't print
        }

        dialog
    } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Activity cannot be null")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#alert-dialog

---

Based on the documentation you should not implement onCreateView() Just use onCreateDialog

Answer (score 1):

Call it in onCreateView() method instead of onViewCreated()
oktextview.setOnClickListener(view -> dismiss());

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).